# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springfoundation.model.Contact - maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

My challenge is that I am getting this error even though I have it defined in hibernate.cfg.xml file

**complete stacktrace**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ com.springfoundation.model.Contact] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2149)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2097)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2077)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2030)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1981)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-datasource-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ com.springfoundation.model.Contact] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/>
```

this is the mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.springfoundation.model.Contact" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: First checks: What does the class look like? Did you annotate it with `@Entity`? Is the class available at classpath?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with "resource" identifier in mapping instead of "class" identifier".

Here's an example :

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <mapping resource="com/example/model/Person.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Person.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.example.model">

    <class name="Person" table="Person">
        <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="email"/>
        <property name="firstName"/>
        <property name="lastName"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

### UPDATE:

**pom.xml**

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-one-jar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.apache.cxf.version>2.7.2</org.apache.cxf.version>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.eclipse.jetty.version>8.1.8.v20121106</org.eclipse.jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal> 
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate uses jboss-logging for logging, for the tutorials we will use the sl4fj-simple backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The tutorials use JUnit test cases to illustrate usage -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The tutorials use the H2 in-memory database -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.145</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>${org.eclipse.jetty.version}</version>            
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
      <version>${org.eclipse.jetty.version}</version>            
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Comment: This is a dependency issue, are you using maven, can you post the pom or the libraries?

Comment: I just added the pom.xml of my little project so you can compare with yours. Also, be careful, it's an old project made in Java 6 so you probably won't have the same version of libraries.